# How to return a value inside a loop in a return method?

Tags: java, loops, methods, return, return-value

I have troubles returning a value from a loop in method.

I've tried this way: (which returns `classname`, my initialise String instead of `classes.get(i).className`)

```
public String getClassName(){
    String cName = "classname";
    for (int i=0; i<classes.size(); i++){
        cName = classes.get(i).className;
    }
return cName;
}
```

and I've tried this as well: (which returns `c` instead of `classes.get(i).className`)

```
public String getClassName(){
    String cName = "classname";
    String c = "c";
    for (int i=0; i<classes.size(); i++){
        c = classes.get(i).className;
    }
    cName = c;
    return cName;
}
```

Please tell me how to return `classes.get(i).className`!! Thanks a lot :P

Comment: Based on what do you need return the value?! Because in your case, the last value from the classes list is getting returned.

Comment: Does it mean that my code has no problem but there's actually nothing stored in the ArrayList, so it returns the initialsed value?

Comment: Yes and no. Syntactically, your code is correct and if there is data in the list, you'd get a different output(not the `className` which you set by default). But logically, its not as it'll always return the last element from the list and I really doubt if you want that, cuz if that's the case, `return classes.get(classes.size() - 1).className;` should suffice. You needn't even iterate through the list.

Comment: @R.J Thanks. but if the `ArrayList classes` has 0 items initially, I am afraid that using`return classes.get(classes.size() - 1).className` would get the `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1` error

Comment: You'd could have a null/empty check for that, before the return. As simple as that. Also, since its a list, you'll get the [`IndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html).

Comment: Should I use `if (classes.size()<=0) return null; else return classes.get(classes.size() - 1).className;`? but I thought we can only return one value in a return method. Can this work?

Comment: Use `classes.isEmpty()` in that case and yes, you can return only 1 value from a method and the logic you gave will also return only 1 value from the method. So no issues.

Comment: Thank you very much. Would you mind helping me out in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617492/failed-to-store-values-in-arraylist-of-class-object ?

Answer (score 1):

There is **nothing stored in classes**. Make sure you have in there what you think you do. Try putting this inside the for loop to see what's going on:

```
System.out.print("class name = " + cName);
```

If this never prints out, you know that classes is empty. At any time *inside* the for loop, you can call **return**, for example if the class name matches something you can test for in an *if* statement.

```
for (int i=0; i<classes.size(); i++){
    cName = classes.get(i).className;
    return cName;
}
```

Also, could you upvote, or mark someone as correct? (I'm new and would love to have some good answers marked as such :)  )

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you trying to do, but your code is equivalent to:

```
public String getClassName() {
    return classes.get(classes.size() - 1).className;
}
```

Are you sure this is what you want to return? You should be careful in case `classes` is empty as you might get [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html).

Comment: Thanks! I've just tried it out and I get this error: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1`

Comment: Means your classes object is empty.

Comment: @Sue Because `classes` is empty.

Comment: That's because your `classes` is empty.

Comment: Thanks. Seems some other parts of my program has problem :(

Answer (score 0):

While Maroun is right bout the code only returning the last value in the classes collection, the reality is that in your example the collection is always empty, and thus the for loop does not execute even once. Make sure the classes collection contain what you think it should!

Comment: I see! So does it mean that there's actually nothing stored in `classes`?

Comment: yes ... that is what I said, and also what I mean (and now this comment is long enough)

Answer (score 0):

That should be because you dont enter the for loop mainly because you list "classes" is empty.
You can check it this way-

```
if(classes.size()==0)
   System.out.println("Classes is empty");
```