# Failed to store values in ArrayList of class object. (CODE EDITED)

Tags: java, class, oop, object, arraylist

This is basically a Java code converter. It involves a GUI let user input class type, name and method. To store the values, I've created a class `VirtualClass` with an `ArrayList<VirtualClass> classes` to store variables `boolean isPrivate`, `String className` and `String methodName`. However, I found that nothing was stored into the `ArrayList`...please help me to see what's the problem

Below is the class `VirtualClass`

```
import java.util.*;

public class VirtualClass {

    private static ArrayList<VirtualClass> classes = new ArrayList<VirtualClass>();
    private boolean isPrivate;
    private String className;
    private String methodName;

    public void setVirtualClass(String name, String method, boolean isP){
        this.className = name;
        this.isPrivate = isP;
        this.methodName = method;
    }

    public void createClass(String name, String method, boolean isP){
        this.className = name;
        this.isPrivate = isP;
        this.methodName = method;
        classes.add(this);
    }
```

For reference, here's some relevant code from  the GUI which let users create class

```
public class GuiAddClass extends JFrame{
    private VirtualClass stObject;
        ...

private class Handler implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

        String cName = inputClassName.getText();
        String mName = inputMethodName.getText();
        boolean isP = true;

        if (classObject.checkName(cName) == false){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Class name invalid. " +
                    "\nEntered name should not contain java keywords or equal to other existing names. " +
                    "\nPlease try again."); 

        } else if (classObject.checkName(cName) == true) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Class saved."); 
                    // this message pane has popped up
            cName = inputClassName.getText();
            mName = inputMethodName.getText();

            if (event.getSource() == publicButton) {
                isP = false;
            } else if (event.getSource() == privateButton) {
                isP = true;
            }
            stObject = new VirtualClass();
            stObject.createClass(cName, mName, isP);
        }

    }// end actionPerformed()

}// end Handler class
```

And here's a couple of methods from another class for display the final javaCode

```
public String getClassName(){
    String cName = "classname";
    String c = "c";
    for (int i=0; i<classes.size(); i++){
        c = classes.get(i).className;
    }
    cName = c;
    return cName;
}    

public String getMethodName(){
    String mName = "methodname";
    String m = "m";
    for (int i=0; i<classes.size(); i++){
    m = classes.get(i).methodName;
    }
    mName = m;
    return mName;
}

public boolean getIsPrivate(){
    boolean isP = false;
    for (int i=0; i<classes.size(); i++){
        isP = classes.get(i).isPrivate;
    }
    return isP;
}
```

Here's the method to generate the Java code

```
    public String getJavaCode(){
        String javaCode = (classObject.getPublic() + " class " + 
stObject.getClassName() + stObject.getListSize() + 
"{\n"+"\t"+"public void "+stObject.getMethodName()+"{\n"+"\t}"+"\n}");
        return javaCode;
```

And what would display in my programme is like this, where c should be class name, m should be method name, and `0 = classes.size()`

```
public class c0{
    public void m{
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to spot out the problem please?
I just have no idea and the answers I received doesn't seem to work. Please help!

Comment: `I found that nothing was stored into the ArrayList` how do you know that nothing stored in?

Comment: It would get stored, if the control went to the `else if`.

Comment: I have asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617263/how-to-return-a-value-inside-a-loop-in-a-return-method?noredirect=1#comment29121536_19617263 and the method in the question is supposed to return values stored in my `ArrayList`. but it returned the initialised value of the string

Comment: How do you determine that nothing was stored into the ArrayList?

Comment: @R.J thanks, I'll see if its the `true false` goes wrong

Comment: @Sue: If you print `classes.size();` what do you see?

Comment: @ JB Nizet @ Maxim Shoustin, I've asked this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617263/how-to-return-a-value-inside-a-loop-in-a-return-method?noredirect=1#comment29121536_19617263 about a failed return method, and people said it failed because the `ArrayList` stored no values.

Comment: @anubhava I've got `0` so I am sure nothing is stored in the list

Comment: @R.J it did go to `else if` because the `messageDialog` had popped up

Answer (score 1):

From information you posted, seems strange that you initiate `VirtualClass stObject` into `actionPerformed` method. Its mean that each time you recreate your object.

Make your `VirtualClass stObject` to be **global** for example, like:

```
private VirtualClass stObject;

...

stObject = new VirtualClass();

private class Handler implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

    ...

   stObject.createClass(cName, mName, isP);
```

Comment: I've got syntax error on `stObject = = new VirtualClass();`. Should I add this line just before `handler`?

Comment: Sorry, its mistake, use `=`. fixed my answer

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems with your code. But mainly, you creational logic does not make much sense. You should not add an instance into your Static collection using a method of the instance. My advice would be to use a static factory method to do this. Something like this instead :

```
public class VirtualClass {

private static List<VirtualClass> classes = new ArrayList<VirtualClass>();
private boolean isPrivate;
private String className;
private String methodName;

//A private constructor
private VirtualClass(String name, String method, boolean isP){
    this.className = name;
    this.isPrivate = isP;
    this.methodName = method;
}

private void setClassName(String className){
    this.className = className;
}

private void getClassName(){
    return className;
}

public static VirtualClass createClass(String name, String method, boolean isP){
    VirtualClass virtualClass = new VirtualClass(String name, String method, boolean isP);
    classes.add(virtualClass);
    return virtualClass;
}
}
```

The way your code is done now, the problems can be in a lot of places in your client classes. This structure is safer and generally used.

Also you should not type your collection with ArrayList but use the implemented interface instead, List. [how to use an array list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697182/how-to-use-an-array-list)

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand this sentence `you should not type your collection with ArrayList but use the implemented interface instead`. Do you mean that I should set `VirtualClass` as a interface, and let other classes `implement VirtualClass` to get its values?

Comment: No, what I meand is the ArrayList type is a Raw Java Type and it is not a good practice to use it according to java specs. You should use the List interface instead. Look at my declaration of my static collection, it is something like this, `private static List<E> classes = new ArrayList<E>()`

Comment: and is it a must for me to use a `private constructor`? Can I use `setVirtualClass` instead? and can I access the attributes inside the List interface?

Comment: I see. Thanks! I've just checked List interface out. I don't know about this type before :) thanks for teaching me!

Comment: It would make things a lot easier in your code. However you could remove what I did, have a public constructor and your setter method and add a static method that would add your instance into your collection. It depends of your intent. What I added is a way to ensure that all your instanced ends up in your array. But nothing prevents you add setters for your instance so they can be changed at creation. I will edit my code to show you how I would do it.

Comment: Thanks you! It's just `List inferface` is fairly new to me, maybe I need some time to get familiar with it. But I need to finish the project asap...so I just hope I can make it work first.

Comment: I've just tried your edited code, and it seems it doesn't work. Now the GUI displays `null` instead of the string