# How to add multiple values to an Object ArrayList?

Tags: java, class, oop, object, arraylist

The problem should be on the `createClass()` method... is it wrong to use `classes.add(this)`?

```
private static ArrayList<VirtualClass> classes = new ArrayList<VirtualClass>();
private boolean isPrivate;
private String className;
private String methodName;

public void setVirtualClass(String name, String method, boolean isP){
    this.className = name;
    this.isPrivate = isP;
    this.methodName = method;
}

public void createClass(String name, String method, boolean isP){
    this.className = name;
    this.isPrivate = isP;
    this.methodName = method;
    classes.add(this);
}
```

More details on the problem: [Failed to store values in ArrayList of class object. (CODE EDITED)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617492/failed-to-store-values-in-arraylist-of-class-object-code-edited/19617757?noredirect=1#comment29122248_19617757)

Comment: what do you want to add to the "classes" list ?

Comment: Don't ask the same question again and again. Learn to use a debugger, and step through the code to understand what is actually executes. It's not inherently wrong, but it doesn't look like good design. Static mutable variables are always a smell anyway.

Comment: Your question should be self-contained: what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to keep a record of all created classes?

It is generally bad practice to pass out `this` in a constructor because, by definition, `this` hasn't been constructed yet. In this instance I don't think it will cause problems but it certainly doesn't smell right.

I would consider using a `static` factory method or another form of factory pattern so that you can split up object creation and the storing of instances.

Answer (score 0):

No one can tell you whether it is right or wrong unless you tell what you are trying to do.

If what you are doing is something like : (assume your class is called Foo)

```
Foo foo = new Foo();

foo.createClass("Blablabla", "method1", true);
foo.createClass("AnotherClass", "method2", true);
```

something like that, then yes, you are probably wrong. Because what you are doing is simply changing the only Foo instance with different attribute, and adding the same object to the list.